# Unable to scroll to correct RecyclerView position using onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() on rotation of device

Tags: android

I am a beginner in Android development. I tried to save the state of RecyclerView's LayoutManager using onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() on the LayoutManager (after going through a lot of StackOverflow questions) but I am unable to do so.I wish to restore the scroll position of the RecyclerView on rotation of the device. I have also tried saving the position of the NestedScrollView used in the layout but couldnt get it to work too.

Fragment Class

```
public class RecipeDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String BUNDLE_RECIPE_ID = "Recipe";
    private static final String BUNDLE_LAYOUT_MANAGER_KEY = "layout";
    public StepAdapter mStepAdapter;
    public IngredientAdapter mIngredientAdapter;
    private Recipe selectedRecipe;
    private StepAdapter.StepAdapterOnClickHandler mClickHandler;

    @BindView(R.id.rv_recipe_detail_steps)
    RecyclerView mStepRecyclerView;

    @BindView(R.id.rv_recipe_detail_ingredients)
    RecyclerView mIngredientRecyclerView;


    public RecipeDetailFragment() {
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recipe_detail, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

        mIngredientAdapter = new IngredientAdapter();
        mIngredientRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        mIngredientRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mIngredientRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

        mStepAdapter = new StepAdapter(getContext(), mClickHandler);
        mStepRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        mStepRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mStepRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            selectedRecipe = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(BUNDLE_RECIPE_ID);
        }
        mIngredientAdapter.setIngredientData(selectedRecipe.getIngredients());

        mStepAdapter.setStepData(selectedRecipe.getSteps());

        mIngredientRecyclerView.setAdapter(mIngredientAdapter);

        mStepRecyclerView.setAdapter(mStepAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

            Parcelable state = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(BUNDLE_LAYOUT_MANAGER_KEY);
            mStepRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        }
    }


    public void setRecipe(Recipe recipe) {
        selectedRecipe = recipe;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            mClickHandler = (StepAdapter.StepAdapterOnClickHandler) context;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelable(BUNDLE_RECIPE_ID, selectedRecipe);
        outState.putParcelable(BUNDLE_LAYOUT_MANAGER_KEY, mStepRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()
                .onSaveInstanceState());

    }
}
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/recipe_detail_nested_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/ll_recipe_detail_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:cardView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/ingredients_card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            cardView:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            cardView:cardElevation="4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_recipe_detail_ingredients_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/label_ingredients"

                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionMode.Title"
                    android:textSize="28sp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/rv_recipe_detail_ingredients"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:cardView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/steps_card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            cardView:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            cardView:cardElevation="4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_recipe_detail_steps_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                    android:text="@string/label_steps"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionMode.Title"
                    android:textSize="28sp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rv_recipe_detail_steps"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:paddingBottom="16dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

P.S. This is my first time posting a question here so if I have not posted the question correctly please let me know!

Comment: on the save instance state, have you tried `mStepRecyclerView.getAdapterPosition()` ?

Comment: Yeah. Didnt work somehow . When i tried to retrieve the view using the adapter position in onCreateView() it returned a null view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> as you are using fragment make sure you not doing fragment transaction when savedInstanceState is not null in activity that host the fragment as on rotation activity is recreated
>   first of all you need to save the data you pass to adapter in savedInstanceState  and if savedInstanceState is not null use that data
>
> and use this custom recyclerview

```html
package eu.f3rog.ui.custom;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

/**
 * Class {@link StatefulRecyclerView} extends {@link RecyclerView} and adds position management on configuration changes.
 *
 * @author FrantisekGazo
 * @version 2016-03-15
 */
public final class StatefulRecyclerView
        extends RecyclerView {

    private static final String SAVED_SUPER_STATE = "super-state";
    private static final String SAVED_LAYOUT_MANAGER = "layout-manager-state";

    private Parcelable mLayoutManagerSavedState;

    public StatefulRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public StatefulRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public StatefulRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(SAVED_SUPER_STATE, super.onSaveInstanceState());
        bundle.putParcelable(SAVED_LAYOUT_MANAGER, this.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState());
        return bundle;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        if (state instanceof Bundle) {
            Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
            mLayoutManagerSavedState = bundle.getParcelable(SAVED_LAYOUT_MANAGER);
            state = bundle.getParcelable(SAVED_SUPER_STATE);
        }
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    }

    /**
     * Restores scroll position after configuration change.
     * <p>
     * <b>NOTE:</b> Must be called after adapter has been set.
     */
    private void restorePosition() {
        if (mLayoutManagerSavedState != null) {
            this.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(mLayoutManagerSavedState);
            mLayoutManagerSavedState = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(Adapter adapter) {
        super.setAdapter(adapter);
        restorePosition();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I didnt check that my fragment was being created twice as I had not checked for value of savedInstanceState. Putting the beginning of transaction within if(savedInstanceState == null) solved it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As long as your `RecyclerView` has an `id` set, you should not have to do anything to get it to save its scroll state when you rotate your device. Here is a very simple app that demonstrates this.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        recycler.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());
    }

    private static class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemview, parent, false);
            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.text.setText("" + position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 100;
        }
    }

    private static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final TextView text;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>
```

itemview.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        tools:text="Hello world"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This didn't really help me. I am using the RecyclerView as a childView of a CardView which itself is a childView of the layout. I have already set an id for the RecyclerView but it does not restore the scroll state

Comment: How is the data in your recyclerview's adapter populated? The system's auto-restore functionality won't work if the data's not there by the time the recyclerview goes to restore its position.

Comment: I store the data required in onSaveInstanceState() which is then passed to the adapter which uses it to populate the RecyclerView

Comment: Where do you retrieve the data? In which lifecycle callback method?

Comment: onCreateView() callback